# Удалить объекты без учета части идентификатора

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

```
<div class="row">
   <span id="status-account-year">
   <span id="status-account-month">
   <span id="status-account-day">
</div>
```

Как пройтись циклом по **.row** и удалить все `span` у которых в идентификаторе есть **status-account-**

```
$('#status-account-???').remove();
```

P.s: Код ниже не подходит, т.к есть другие `span`

```
$('.row').each(function(){
  $(this).find('span').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для выбора элементов, значение атрибутов которых содержит по крайней мере одно вхождение строки как подстроки `[attr*=value]`:

```
$('.row span[id*="status-account-"]').remove();
```

---

В вашем случае лучше использовать [атрибутивный селектор](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) `[attr^=value]` элементов, значение атрибутов которых начинается с `value`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.row span[id^="status-account-"]').remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <span id="status-account-year">1</span>
  <span id="status-account-month">2</span>
  <span id="status-account-day">3</span>
  <span id="another">4</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.row').find('span').each(function() {
  const id = $(this).attr('id');
  if (id.indexOf('status-account-') !== -1) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <span id="status-account-year">1</span>
   <span id="status-account-month">2</span>
   <span id="status-account-day">3</span>
   <span id="another">4</span>
</div>
```